# inserting dataframe into MySQL table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mysql-python

I am trying to insert a data frame from Python to MySQL and facing below error. **"Content"** is my Table in MySQL. **"Master_df"** is my Dataframe in Python. I have "Master_df" dataframe which consists of close to 200 observations and all the columns are text data.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxxxx',
                          host='localhost',
                          database='Database',
                          use_pure=False)


mycurser = cnx.cursor()

mycurser.execute("INSERT INTO Content (URL, Content, Category) VALUES (%S, %S, %S)", Master_df)


cnx.close()
```

> File
> "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line
> 1576, in **nonzero**
> .format(self.**class**.**name**
> ))
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Can you post your entire script? We have no idea what is going on from one line.

Comment: I have added the code